# 9398 problem with the front wheels

Tags: technic

I've just finished [9398 4x4 Crawler](http://brickset.com/sets/9398-1). The rear motor works properly, but the front motor doesn't: The wheels seem to be locked, although they spin freely when I turn them by hand.
What could be the problem?

Comment: In my version of the set, there is an extra sheet pointing towards this particular piece. It is not a mistake in the instruction, but they put in an additional picture to clarify how it is done correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Check if [Cross Block 90°](http://brickset.com/parts/4211775) that is placed in step 53 of instruction book 1 is in the correct orientation with the round hole placed over the motor axle.

Mounting it the other way will prevent rotation of the motor.

Comment: YOU DID! Solved! One piece in a wrong position and everything locked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cezar Then you should also mark this answer as the correct one to give Joost proper credit!